# Followers / Following structure in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

My website has a 'follow' feature, where users can follow each other.

---

Ideally, a user1 would be able to follow a user2, and have their _id present inside user2.followers, aswell as user2 should be present in user1.following.

My first thought was to simply do something like

```
/*
  UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    followers: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
      }
    ],
    following: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
      }
    ]
  })
*/

// POST /api/users/follow
let user = await User.findById(userId)
let follow = await User.findById(followId)

if (!user || !follow) {
  return errorHandle()
}

user.following.push(follow._id);
follow.followers.push(user._id);

user.save();
follow.save();

/*
  User.findById(userId)
  .populate('following', 'username')
  .then(user => console.log(user.following))
*/
```

But these would be difficult to scale and maintain (as well as other problems).

So I want to hear from you, the stack community, what a proper way to deal with this system be, as I am new to MongoDB and Databases as a whole.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

hey I was getting the same problem I figured it out how it can be done. I have two way of writing the code choose as per your choice.

**UserSchema**

```
  var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    following: [
    {

        user:{ 
            type: Schema.ObjectId, 
            ref: 'User' 
        },
    }

],
followers: [
    {

        user:{ 
            type: Schema.ObjectId, 
            ref: 'User' 
        },
    }
],
    date:{
        type:Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
});
```

**First Method**

**User.js**

You can use .then and .catch method

```
    router.post("/user/:user_id/follow-user", (req,res) => {

    // finding user by id (to whom user is going to follow)

    User.findById(req.params.user_id)
        .then(user => {

            //check if follow reqest by user2 is already exist in user1 followers

               if(user.followers.filter(follower => follower.user.toString()=== req.user._id).length > 0 ){
                return res.status(400).json({ alreadyLike : "User already like the post"})
            }

            // the requested user will push and save to followers of other user to whom request has made

            user.followers.push(req.user._id);
            var followedUser = user._id;
            user.save()

            // we will find current user by email you can find it by _id also

            User.findOne({ email: req.user.email })
                .then(user => {

                    // now push the user to following of its own and save the user

                    user.following.push(followedUser);
                    user.save().then(user => res.json(user))
                })
                .catch(err => console.log("error cant follow again you jave already followed the user"))
        })
})
```

**second method**

Normal method by call backs

```
    router.post("/user/:user_id/follow-user",  (req,res) => {

    // finding user by id (to whom user is going to follow)

    User.findById(req.params.user_id, function(err, user) {

        // the requested user will push and save to followers of other user to whom request has made

        user.followers.push(req.user._id);
        var followedUser = user._id;
        user.save(function(err){
            if(err){

                console.log(err)
            }
            else
            {

                // Secondly, find the user account for the logged in user

                User.findOne({ email: req.user.email }, function(err, user) {

                    user.following.push(followedUser);
                    user.save(function(err){
                        if(err){
                            console.log(err)
                        }
                        else{
                            //send success response
                            res.json(user)
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```